# bootstrap3 calendar is not working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

Bootstrap datepicker is opening the calendar before even selecting the calendar and in the calendar it is also not possible to select any date as well.

**html ---**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
     <h6>datetimepicker1</h6>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Script** ---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker()({
    });
  });
</script>
```

Output ---

[image]

it should look like ---

[image]

Can anyone help how i can get a bootstrap calendar which is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing the libraries that your code needed:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
         <h6>datetimepicker1</h6>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
                <input type="text" class="form-control"> <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Have a look at your **JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/anoorally/3mno4ba3/) code with the libraries included.

Pay attention to the *external* libraries included.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
            <input type="text" id="datepick" class="form-control" />  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Script**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $('#datepick').datepicker()({
        });
      });
      $('datetimepicker1').click(function(){
   $('#datepick').datepicker('show');
});
    </script>
```

I think this will work for u